# select query for time interval in mysql and php

Tags: php, mysql

select query to select all records that were inserted in 15 minutes.for ex if now time is 10:00 then it shoulld fetch all record inserted from 9:45 to 10:00

Comment: And the datatype of your insertion_time field?

Comment: Your first stop when asking yourself the question "how do I query for ..." should be the MySQL reference, for date time functions you can find all info at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html.

Answer (score 6):

Assuming you have a `DATETIME` column named `created` in your table:

```
SELECT id FROM tablename 
WHERE ((created > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 15 MINUTE))
  AND (created < NOW()))
```

Comment: What's the second condition for? To prevent against time traveling?

Comment: @Artefacto you never know! :)

Comment: `if bool(foo) == True and True is True: print 'foo is True'`

Comment: @shylent not true. It is perfectly possible to insert future dates into the `created` column. There is no native mySQL way to stop anybody from doing so. Better safe than sorry.

Comment: @Pekka: don't be so boring :) Although I do, obviously, see your point

Comment: @shylent Finding and fixing a bug caused by something like this is *way* more boring! :)

Comment: Well, I've never said, that your query was wrong or redundant.

Comment: @shylent I know. Just teasing back :)

Comment: thanks 4 help its working...
INTERVAL 15 MINUTE i need to set this as a variable how can i do it?

Comment: @mayuri You mean as a PHP variable? Just insert it into your query, nothing special to it. As a mySQL field, I'm not sure it can be done.

Comment: i want the time to be changed dynamically later so i needed

Comment: @mayuri that is impossible to answer, as you are giving no information about the context you are working in. Check out constants in PHP, maybe they are what you need. http://www.php.net/constants

Comment: i want to fetch the records that were entered in last 15 mins, from that if the number of failures are more then 5 i want to block further login so i want that time i e 15 minutes to change later so need to make it dynamic..forgive for my english

Comment: @mayuri Put it in a variable? I don't know what your question is.

Comment: @PEKKA SELECT status FROM `login_attempts` WHERE lastlogin BETWEEN NOW() AND 1500 1500 is minutes in seconds is this correct can i use this?please help its urgent

Comment: @mayuri just store `$variable = "INTERVAL 15 MINUTE";` and use `$variable` in the query. It won't make much sense though as you can change it in the code anyway. The usual way is to define a constant in the top of the file: `define("QUERY_INTERVAL", "15 MINUTE");` and then to use the constant in the query: "SELECT ..... BETWEEN (NOW(), INTERVAL".QUERY_INTERVAL.")");` Constants are explained in the link I posted above.

Answer (score 2):

```
select * from table WHERE datetimeField BETWEEN date_add(NOW(),INTERVAL -15 MINUTE) AND NOW();
```